# International validation is not working with SmartyStreets plugin

Tags: javascript, forms, api, validation, smartystreets

## [SmartyStreets Plugin](https://smartystreets.com/docs/plugins/website)

### International Validation Woes

I have done everything the walk through requires:

1. Included the Plugin

`<script src="//d79i1fxsrar4t.cloudfront.net/jquery.liveaddress/3.1/jquery.liveaddress.min.js"></script>`

2. Configured Plugin Settings

```js
var ss = jQuery.LiveAddress({
    key: '******',
    waitForStreet: true, 
    debug: true,
    target: "US|International",
    addresses: [{
      address1: "#line1",
      address2: "#line2",
      locality: "#city",
      administrative_area: "#state",
      postal_code: "#zip",
      country: "#country"
    }]
});
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" id="country" name="country" placeholder="country"><br>
    <input type="text" id="line1" name="line1" placeholder="line1"><br>
    <input type="text" id="line2" name="line2" placeholder="line2"><br>
    <input type="text" id="city" name="city" placeholder="city"><br>
    <input type="text" id="state" name="state" placeholder="state"><br>
    <input type="text" id="zip" name="ZIP" placeholder="ZIP"><br>
</form>
```

Still however, validation will not work for other countries outside the US?

Comment: Can you add more details please? what time of forms are you using? which JS plug-ins? and if there is HTML you can post

Answer (score 0):

After some time trying alternative configurations and still not having any luck, I contacted the Smartystreets.com support team. It turns out your account must be whitelisted in order for you to test out the International API.

Currently, the only way to get permission to test out International API is to contact them directly. I used the chat on their site, but you can also email them at *support@smartystreets.com*. Once you do, they will send you an email that you have to 'Agree to Terms' and reply back to. Shortly after they will unlock [International Validation](https://smartystreets.com/docs/international-street-api) for your account.